# error using tf.estimator.Estimator cnn tutorial

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to run a similar file as the CNN tutorial found in Tensor Flow:

```
mnist_classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(
model_fn=cnn_model_fn, model_dir="/tmp/mnist_convnet_model")
```

and I get the following error:

```
File "tfCNNMNIST.py", line 77, in main
mnistClassifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=convNet, 
model_dir="/tmp/mln_MNIST2")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'estimator'
```

I searched in google and I updated my tensorflow version using the following command:

```
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
```

I run the program again and I got the same error.

What should I do to run the program?

Comment: Can you post the output of `pip3 list`. Also can you post how you are trying to execute the file? Make sure you're using the Python associated with your pip.

Comment: After some hours playing around with it I fixed it, thanks :)

Comment: The problem was that I did not have root authorization. I uninstall tensorflow as a --user and then installed it again. After that my code compiled :)